# rails 4 jquery autocomplete text for no results

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, autocomplete

I have the [rails-4-jquery-autocomplete](https://github.com/peterwillcn/rails4-autocomplete) gem installed. I'm using it on my registration page (done by devise) where a user selects their school. The problem I'm currently having is that I want to show a text, e.g., "My school is not listed" when there are no schools found. Currently, by default the text, "no existing match" is shown, i want to change that text.

[image]

Looking at the documentation for the gem, I don't see a way to set the text for when there are no results found. Is there a way to override the gem and return a different string if it doesn't find any results? Or, will i need to modify the jquery call?

**SuggestionController**

```
class SuggestionsController < ApplicationController
  autocomplete :school, :name, :full => true
end
```

**View**

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div>
    <%= f.label :school_id %>
    <%= f.autocomplete_field :school_name, autocomplete_school_name_suggestions_path %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Add all relevant code

Comment: @Dave, My mistake, the view code has now been added in.

Comment: I understand that your question has been answered, but an official/new version of the gem has been released, and it actively maintained. https://github.com/bigtunacan/rails-jquery-autocomplete

Comment: @theStig Just re-iterating what Hunter Stevens said.  The officially maintained gem supports the feature you are looking for out of the box these days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `"no existing match"` message is inserted by the autocomplete-rails-uncompressed.js file on line 61 [here](https://github.com/peterwillcn/rails4-autocomplete/blob/af20d97e33807dba5176512df5ece048d4435bea/lib/assets/javascripts/autocomplete-rails-uncompressed.js#L61):

```
if(arguments[0].length == 0) {
  arguments[0] = []
  arguments[0][0] = { id: "", label: "no existing match" }
}
```

It looks like that string is hardcoded, so there is no way for you to customize the empty message without some extra effort on your end.

An easy solution would be to remove the line

```
//= require autocomplete-rails
```

from your `application.js` file then copy and paste the `autocomplete-rails-uncompressed.js` file into your javascripts folder, and alter the `"no existing match"` string to your preferred phrase. The drawback to this approach is that if this gem were to be updated in the future, it would be up to you to update your modified javascript file.

A better and more involved solution would be to fork the gem and alter the javascript logic to accept options other than `"no existing match"`. Once that is implemented, you could then submit a pull request to get your new and improved logic merged into master.

Answer (score 0):

Using the official version of the gem at https://github.com/bigtunacan/rails-jquery-autocomplete you will have support for this feature out of the box.

You just set the text to your desired value as follows.

```
jQuery.railsAutocomplete.options.noMatchesLabel = "New Text Value Here";
```

Or if you would prefer to not show a message at all you can disable it altogether.

```
jQuery.railsAutocomplete.options.showNoMatches = false;
```

---

Something like the following can be added either to the bottom of the application.js file; or (better) as a separate .js file in `assets/javascripts` and then that file would need to be added as a directive to the application.js file AFTER the directive which references rails-jquery-autocomplete.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery.railsAutocomplete.options.noMatchesLabel = "New Text Value Here";
})
```

Comment: would you know where to actually set the text: in the application .js file or where else? any advice much appreciated

Comment: @BKSpurgeon I've added some additional details above.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to disable the no match message for just one input field you can add a data-attribute to the specific field:

```
<%= f.autocomplete_field :school_name, autocomplete_school_name_suggestions_path, 'data-show-no-matches' => false %>
```